# mysql dont repeat

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in the table a field named chapter and the chapter is usually repeated in the entry, but I want to not repeat in the output Vjrj name of the chapter once and under it have the names registered

Comment: this is not a mysql sql issue  ..  you should resolve you prensentation aspect at presentation level ..  server/side or client/side..

Comment: You should use `distinct` select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword in the sql query to prevent getting repeated values.

Answer (score 0):

SQL output is in columns and rows. So it seems you want to select NULL as chapter for rows where the previous row contains the same chapter. This can be done with using `LAG` (available as of MySQL 8):

```
select
  case when chapter = lag(chapter) over (order by chapter, col1) then null else chapter end,
  col2,
  col3
from mytable
order by chapter, col1;
```

But I would usually rather select the data without supression and care about that in the presentation layer (app or Website) instead.